# property of a locally cyclic group

Tags: infinite-groups

How to prove a locally cyclic group $(G,.)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of quotient of $\mathbb{Q}$

I've seen this statement written everywhere but without proof and I couldn't prove it (actually its a iff condition and other part is obvious, but for this part getting no idea)

Comment: A finite cyclic group is locally cyclic, so this is not true. It looks to me like you are missing a hypothesis or two.

Comment: hmm right, edited

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Locally_cyclic_iff_subquotient_of_rationals